# How to set up the max-width of $mdDialog?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

I'm a new one in css and can not to set up the max-width of my confirmation dialog properly. Here my code of calling dialog:

```
this.$mdDialog.show({
  content: longText,
  ok: 'OK',
  cancel: 'CANCEL'
  clickOutsideToClose: true,
});
```

The problem is that my `longText` doesn't carry and my dialog is very stretched horizontally. 
I tried to add `style.less` locally and determine `max-width` like this:

```
.md-dialog {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

But there is no changes.
Could some one help me?

Comment: Can you please copy here your view code?

Comment: @developer033 do you mean the code from browser?

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To achieve what you want you should use this way:

```
.md-dialog-content {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: I have tried do like you wrote already. But it makes no sense. I think the problem my confirmation dialog calling from `globalService`. Am I right?

Comment: Even if you put only `.md-dialog-content {` instead of the 2 classes?

Comment: Nope. It is corret only if I change my `confirm.html` in `globalService`. If I add these lines in my local `style.less` there is no sense.

Comment: By the way I think I can mark your post as answer because of my hard architecture in project.

Comment: See their code on *codepen* https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog, if you change the CSS as I said, it changes the *width* as well,.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
md-dialog{
max-width: 300px;
}
```

because md-dialog is not a class it is directive which angular material predefine